# Cluster analysis on related factors

Tags: clustering, pca, graph-theory

I am analyzing a public data set of [information security incident data](http://vcdb.org) and trying to find "clusters" of related factors.

Specifically, each incident is analyzed using [VERIS](http://veriscommunity.net) for the actor's variety (e.g. actor.external.variety = hacktivist or actor.internal.variety = sysadmin) and motive (e.g. actor.motive = grudge) as well as the action's variety (e.g. action.hacking.variety = DoS or action.social.variety = phishing). The possible [enumerations](http://www.veriscommunity.net/doku.php?id=enumerations) are pre-determined. In terms of size, I have a few thousand incidents and a few hundred factors / features, so it's large enough to make manual analysis difficult but small enough that runtime rarely becomes an issue.

I want to find "clusters" that represent highly-correlated sets of factors, or incident patterns. As an example, we know that ideology motives and hacktivists and denial-of-service attacks frequently occur together.

My current approach has been to create a sort of boolean matrix, where the rows are the individual incidents and the columns are the factors of interest. (This means I'm intentionally excluding things like asset data for now because those aren't the focus of my research.) Then, for each factor, I add up all the times it co-occurs with each other factor and build a weighted graph out of that to look for cliques and similar. Although it's been somewhat productive, I don't think this is the "right" approach. I also considered PCA for dimensionality reduction followed by kNN or similar for clustering.

So my question is **what statistical / ML techniques best lend themselves to finding incident patterns in this type of data set?**